# How to get panic information (i.e. stack trace) with `catch_unwind`?

Tags: rust, error-handling, panic

If using `set_hook`, we can get lots of information, especially the stack trace - which is very helpful. However, with `catch_unwind`, I only get a `Result` which contains almost no useful information at all. Therefore, I wonder how to get panic information (especially stack trace) with Rust's `catch_unwind`?

I am in a *multi-threading* environment, where there are many threads concurrently running and any can panic. I guess I should use `set_hook` together with `catch_unwind`, and also uses some thread-local variables, but I am not sure about whether it is feasible and the details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving backtrace from a panic in hook in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54917373/retrieving-backtrace-from-a-panic-in-hook-in-rust)

Comment: @Kitsu No. I want to have backtrace *at the code of* catch_unwind, instead of at the code inside set_hook.

Comment: Actually there will be backtrace for catch_unwind, you just need to filter some items: [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3c1532af5cd6a3ae07c9212d95f66532).

Comment: @Kitsu Sorry I mean, in your example, `main() {let _ = std::panic::catch_unwind(f); GET_BACKTRACE_HERE; }`. I want backtrace at `GET_BACKTRACE_HERE` https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=80d112cb128b4de4062c890b1c4ae1fe

Comment: Actually backtrace at hook contains it as sub-bactrace:

```
  11: playground::g
             at src/main.rs:8:13
  12: playground::main
             at src/main.rs:16:5
```

For release mode it's inlined, so you can add `#[inline(never)]` to have the similar result.

Comment: @Kitsu I know. The problem is: we do have backtrace at the `set_hook`'s callback, but how can I transfer that value to the `GET_BACKTRACE_HERE` location? I may use ThreadLocal, but is that safe? (e.g. when multithreading, or multi-panic happens? I am not familiar with panics)

Comment: Oh, now I got it. That's interesting one, I think thread-local should work: [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0c79bfd969899cc391a3da79ec1643d7).

Comment: Thank you! You can make it an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a backtrace in the panic hook by using the [backtrace](https://crates.io/crates/backtrace) crate, however that doesn't help in [`catch_unwind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) since the stack has already been unwound from where the panic occurred.

What you can do is *smuggle* the backtrace from the panic hook into the catcher by storing it in a [thread local](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.thread_local.html) variable. This *should* be reliable since a panic while panicking is an automatic process abort (so you can't overwrite one that hasn't been caught yet), and panics do not propagate across thread boundaries (joining a panicked thread returns a `Result<_, Box<dyn Any>>` with the panic as the error).

Here's a full example:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use backtrace::Backtrace;

thread_local! {
    static Backtrace: RefCell<Option<Backtrace>> = RefCell::new(None);
}

fn f() {
    panic!("xyz");
}

fn g() {
    if let Err(err) = std::panic::catch_unwind(f) {
        let b = Backtrace.with(|b| b.borrow_mut().take()).unwrap();
        println!("at panic:\n{:?}", b);
    }
}

fn main() {
    std::panic::set_hook(Box::new(|_| {
        let trace = Backtrace::new();
        Backtrace.with(move |b| b.borrow_mut().replace(trace));
    }));
    
    g();
}
```

Comment: Does this work with async?

Comment: @BrandonRos [Yes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=57f69f5707c879f4a01dd6156fff0fbf). The only change would be to use [`.catch_unwind()`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.catch_unwind) from the [futures](https://crates.io/crates/futures) crate instead of `std::panic::catch_unwind`.

Comment: I've got that part, but when the result is an Err, I'm having a hard time getting what seems to be `std::panic::PanicInfo` out of it since it is `Box<dyn Any + Send>`. I'm trying to use `catch_unwind` to get the error message/stack trace of what went wrong. Any tips?

Comment: @BrandonRos The error message can best be retrieved by downcasting the `Box<dyn Any>` into either `&str` or `String`, though it can still be something else if triggered by `panic_any()` ([docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.panic.html)). And as the focus of this question and answer, the backtrace can't be retrieved from the result but must be accessed out-of-band from the `Backtrace` thread-local variable.

Comment: I was hoping the full PanicInfo would be downcastable instead of just the “payload” field from it.